# Append data of multiple files to new file separated by a line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, ip

I have more than a hundred firewall rules for many different customers in discrete files in a folder.

Suppose the filenames are:

1.wawa.com_firewall_rule

2.newa.com_firewall_rule

Each file contains the IPs of the customers.
What I need is to extract the IPs for each customer from the file, and append it to a SINGLE new file in the following format:

```
wawa.com
192.168.1.1
newa.com
8.8.8.8
9.9.9.9
```

Right now, I have been able to extract the IPs and save them in new files.
But I need to save all in a single file. (as a report) - see my code below

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/zeus/zxtm/conf/rules/sba_filter/test
for f in *; do 
#echo $f > hosts.txt
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" "$f" > "$f.txt"
done
```

Comment: try this loop:
for i in *_firewall_rule; do echo ""$i"$(<"$i")"| sed s/_firewall_rule//g > ips.txt; done

Comment: Well, isn't that simply `grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" * > report`?

Comment: Is the host name in the file or do you want to extract it from the file name?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of your input files. What else is there apart from IPs?

Comment: Also, tell us what you want the output to look like.  I know you *show* the output file “format”, but your question title says “separated by a line,” and I don’t understand how the output that you show reflects that requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preserving your work, a possible solution could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/prova
for f in *; do 
  basename $f '_firewall_rule' >> output.txt
  printf "\n" >> output.txt
  grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" "$f" | while read -r line ; do
    echo $line >> output.txt
    printf "\n" >> output.txt
  done
done
```

See optimization contributions in comments

Comment: I haven't profiled, but I would guess that it'd be more efficient, and certainly less error prone to put hte redirection into `output.txt` on the `for` loop itself instead of having each line open the file to append

Comment: Instead of the `while` loop you could write it like this - `grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" "$f" | xargs printf '%s\n\n'`

Comment: (1) You can prevent a lot of noise by saying `for f in *_firewall_rule` instead of `for f in *`. (2) You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$f"` and `"$line"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing. (3) I’m not convinced that you even need to add the blank lines that you’re adding — the OP’s example output doesn’t have blank lines. (I admit that the “separated by a line” qualifier in the question title is puzzling.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) As fd0 points out, there are much better ways of adding blank lines to a data stream than `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; printf "\n"; done`.  I recommend `sed 's/$/\n/'`.  If you want to be cryptic, you could do `paste -d'\n' - /dev/null`. If you insist on using a `while` loop, you could at least trim it down to `while read -r line; do printf "%s\n\n" "$line"; done`. (Or you could use fd0’s suggestion.)  By the way, your current code (with `echo "$line"`) could fail for filenames beginning with a dash (**`-`**).

Answer (score 2):

```
find your_dir -name "*firewall_rule"
-exec basename {} \;
-exec echo \;
-exec grep -P '(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}' {} \;
-exec echo \;
> your_output_file
```

This will (line by line):

- Find all files in **your_dir** ending in "firewall_rule"
- Output a blank line
- Output all [0-999].[0-999].[0-999].[0-999] IP addresses
- Output another blank line
- Send the output to a new file called **your_output_file**

Comment: nice solution Michael, just missing the new line between the ips

Answer (score 2):

You could do it all with awk in a single command if you don't have too many files for the command line to handle:

```
awk --posix 'FNR==1 {f=FILENAME; sub("_firewall_rule", "", f); print f "\n"} /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/ {print $0 "\n"}' *_firewall_rule
```

for my version of `gawk` I needed the `--posix` to get the braces to work right in the regex.

**How it works**

Whenever a new file is started `FNR` will be 1, since it's the first record in the file, so we'll get the filename from the builtin `FILENAME` variable, strip off the `_firewall_rule` part and print what's left with a blank line

Then any line that looks roughly like an IPv4 address we'll print that line with an extra newline on it.

If you didn't want the extra blank lines between all the IPs and the names and such you can remove the `\n` parts of the print, and actually simplify the pattern part like so:

```
awk --posix 'FNR==1 {f=FILENAME; sub("_firewall_rule", "", f); print f} /([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/ ' *_firewall_rule
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. But note that the OP’s use of the `-o` option to `grep` raises the possibility that the input files have other text on the lines that contain the IP addresses — text that should be removed (and not output).

Comment: `/pattern/1;` prints **all** lines; drop the 1 and preferably also the semicolon. @G-Man: `-o` allows _multiple_ IPs _and_ other stuff. `{while(match($0,/patt/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}` **can** handle this, but I'd stick with `grep`.